# Is there any way to protect main activity of the Android application from being launched by the other applications?

Tags: android

By default main activity of my application (HelloWorld  from the Android Studio) is exported and does not require any permission to launch it.

Is there any way to protect my main activity from being launched by the other applications but at the same time leaving the possibility to run the application by the Android device user?

Comment: What is the actual threat you are trying to mitigate?

Comment: E.g. I have two activities - main and the second one. User is using the second one, then malicious application on the phone launch my main activity and thus disturbing using my application (application is forced to back to the main activity)

Comment: I know this threat is very low, but I am just curious if there is any way to mitigate it?

Answer (score 2):

No. After all, the launcher is an application. If you ban applications from starting your activity, you ban the launcher from starting your activity.